# create golang bindings for a python module

Tags: python, go, binding, cpython

I want to write golang bindings for an existing (third party) Python module.
The purpose is that I want to use the API that the Python module provides in Golang.

I already found golang bindings for Python's C API ([go-python3](https://github.com/datadog/go-python3) for py3 and [go-python](https://github.com/sbinet/go-python) for py2), but I still haven't figured out how to translate a relatively complex Python module into Golang (i.e. how to deal with type safety in go for unsafe inputs and returns in python, etc).

What would be a good approach? Are there any pre-existing tools in that space? Are there any good examples for Golang bindings for Python code? (I couldn't find many tbh).

Comment: I think the question is too broad - it would be better to present a small python functionality you would like to call from go. To expect that somebody would explain all possible problems with all possible types of input is just a little bit over the top.

Comment: maybe let me rephrase: Is there any good example for how to use go-python3 or go-python?

Comment: The rephrased question would be off-topic here, as "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow", https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. go-python3 has some examples in the github-repository, why aren't they sufficient for your usecase (what ever that may be)?

Answer (score 12):

> I want to use the API that the Python module provides in Golang.

Calling Python from Go is detailed recently in "[**Python and Go : Part I - gRPC**](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2020/06/python-go-grpc.html)" by [**Miki Tebeka**](https://twitter.com/tebeka).
You can see an example in [`ardanlabs/python-go/grpc`](https://github.com/ardanlabs/python-go/tree/master/grpc)

But, as shown in [their next two articles](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2020/08/packaging-python-code.html), you can also:

- compiled Go code to a shared library and used it from the Python interactive shell.
- use a Python module that hides the low level details of working with a shared library and then package this code as a Python package.

[image: https://www.ardanlabs.com/images/goinggo/124_figure1.png]

Full example: [`ardanlabs/python-go/pyext`](https://github.com/ardanlabs/python-go/tree/master/pyext).

Comment: Your embedded PNG could really do with using a lighter grey (vs black) for the text.. or not using transparency.  In dark mode where the background is `#2D2D2D`  it's rather hard to read (classic light/dark UI conflict, just a suggestion)

Comment: @Rudu THank you. I am surprised this issue reported in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396071/6309 is yet to be solved. In the meantime, all I have to do is save the png in jpg, which loses the transparent effect. I have edited the answer and re-uploaded the picture, now readable in dark mode.

Comment: thanks for the link to this series of blog posts. It was certainly an interesting read, so thank you for it! But: Unfortunately it doesn't answer the question. I'm looking for a way to create golang bindings for a Python module. That means I want to create a golang program that dynamically links to the python DLL (i.e. with the mentioned libraries). I'm looking for advice or a good example how to write Go code that wraps/binds to Python code. (The first article covers grpc calls from a golang to a python process. The second describes writing a Python module in Go - both different topics).

Comment: @Chris I agree, this does not cover fully your question, but since it still allows a Go program to call a Python one, I figured it could be of interest for other readers.